# Why does the chat room no longer support alpha-channel enabled images?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, images, chat

I don't know whether or not it is a local issue. Feel free to migrate to the global meta if necessary.

In my experience in the past, alpha-channel enabled images are displayed correctly in main site, meta site and chat rooms. But now they cannot be displayed correctly in the chat rooms.

For example, the following image is well displayed here,

[image]

but in the chat room, it looks [odd (click)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17225571#17225571). Is it a bug or a new odd feature?

Comment: The above image was created by PSTricks followed by Imagemagick's convert.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What changed is that we started using imgur thumbnails by default in chat; so when you link to `https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSQFI.png`, we *display* `https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSQFIm.png`, but link to the original:

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="//i.stack.imgur.com/DmZBd.png">
    <img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/DmZBdm.png" class="user-image" alt="user image">
</a>
```

The "m" suffix is [part of the imgur api](https://api.imgur.com/models/image), and generates a medium thumbnail, max 320x320 (preserving proportions) - ideal for chat... ish.

This seems to be causing a few problems; I will disable this again - perhaps adding a new syntax for automatically thumbnailed images.